# Repeat a variable with printf

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, printf

if I use the following command:

```
printf "%.0s┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃\n" {1..3}
```

I get an output like this:

```
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
```

How can I achieve the same result with getting the repeated chars from a variable?

I tried this approach:

```
var="┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃"
printf '%.0s%s\n' {1..3} "$var"
```

but it does not work, I end up with this:

```
2
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
$ var="┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃"

$ printf "$var"'%.0s\n' {1..3}

┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃
```

Comment: ok, cheers that is what I have really been looking for...

Answer (score 2):

```
var="┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃   ┃"
printf '%s\n' "$var" "$var" "$var"
```

Comment: ok thanks, I hoped there was a way to concatenate the variables, but I can live with this... :-)

Comment: @nath Maybe they can. I just don't understand what you intend.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I thought my `non-working-example` would show that, but your approach is definitely good to know, the command is only getting a bit long when I would use `{1..100}`, but I did not ask this, really!